# NERDTree causes problems with gvim (v7.3) on windows 7 (x64)

Tags: windows, vim, vim-plugin

GVim reports a lot of errors when I try to open after installing NERDTree.vim in `vimfiles\plugin\` area.

I get many error screens, the first screen's first few errors are as follows ---

```
Error detected while processing .....vimfiles\plugin\NERD_tree.vim:
line    4:
E477: No ! allowed: <!DOCTYPE html>
line    5:
E488: Trailing characters: <html>
line    6:
E488: Trailing characters:   <head>
line    7:
E488: Trailing characters:     <meta charset='utf-8'>
line    8:
E488: Trailing characters:     <meta http-equiv=
line    9:
E488: Trailing characters:         <title>plugin/NERD_tree.vim at master from scrooloose/nerdtree - GitHub</title>
```

Comment: That doesn't look like you downloaded the actual nerdtree plugin file.

Comment: How did you install it? It looks like you downloaded html file from github what you mustn't do.

Answer (score 5):

Like @ZyX and @GWW said, looks like you get the nerdtree.vim file by right click the link in GitHub site and `save the link as ...`, by that way you got a HTML page.

Redownload your nerdtree.vim file at [This Page](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1658), click the lasted `NERD_tree.zip` link, unzip it and replace the nerdtree.vim file.